# On submission function is not being called in custom module

Tags: 7

I have written a custom module for form submission the first time but submit button is not working.

Here is the code:

```
function my_form($form, &$form_state) {

$node = array();
$pl_name=array();
$pl_name=getplaylist_to_edit(arg(1));


$node['text'] = array(
'#type' => 'textfield',
'#id'=>'edit-playlist-name',
'#value' => $pl_name[1],
);

$node['submit'] = array(
'#type' => 'submit',
'#value' => 'Update',
'#submit' => array('test'),
);

return $node;
}


function test()
{
echo '<script>alert("You have submitted the form.");</script>';
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure but I think the variable name could be important: $form instead of $node (because of the parameters).

Comment: Has something led you to believe that randomly `echo`ing something in the middle of a request will do anything at all?

Comment: Just to check whether the function is being called or not the alert is echoing.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try like this:

```
function my_form($form, &$form_state) {
  $pl_name=array();
  $pl_name=getplaylist_to_edit(arg(1));

  $form['text'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#id'=>'edit-playlist-name',
    '#value' => $pl_name[1],
  );

  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => 'Update',
  );

  return $node;
}

function my_form_submit($form, &$form_state){
  echo '<script>alert("You have submitted the form.");</script>';
}
```

Comment: Yes, I had tried it but same problem. Function is not being called.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran something similar to your callback function in my local test enviroment. For me the function was getting called, the echo/print wasn't doing anything. Try using a `drupal_set_message('you have submitted the form');` in stead of echoing out the java call to see if that gets fired.

I'm not 100% sure on this, but I THINK the reason this is happening is due to a redirect or page refresh that's happening after your submit function is called. That would wipe away anything you echo or print out from that function. As a general rule, it's probably best to stick with ether drupal_set_message to print messages out to the user, or download and install [devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) and use dsm() to print out test messages.

Comment: Not even page refresh process is happening.